# Updating product prices

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have a multi store with following structure. The ID is obtain by hovering mouse over the link in the store management.

WebsiteA (http://www.websitea.com/), ID 2
StoreA, ID 2
StoreB, ID 4
StoreC, ID 6

WebsiteB (http://www.websiteb.com/), ID 3
StoreD, ID 3
StoreE, ID 5
StoreF, ID 7

WebsiteA is using USD as base currency while WebsiteB is using AUD. I have another database which host the price list based on the SKU. Catalog Price Scope is configured to “Website”.

I have the following code created as cron to update the price however it doesn’t appear to work properly. Instead it updated all websites with aud price.

```
    foreach($data as $p) {
        $price_usd = $p[‘usdprice’];
        $price_aud =  $p[‘audprice’];
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$p['sku']);
        $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
        if ($product) {
            $product->setPrice($price_usd)->save();
            foreach ( $websites as $website ) {
                $basecurrency = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website)->getBaseCurrencyCode();
                $websiteid = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website)->getId();
                if ( $basecurrency == "USD" ) { 
                    $product->setWebsiteId($websiteid)->setPrice($price_usd)->save();
                }
                elseif  ( $basecurrency == “AUD" ) { 
                    $product->setWebsiteId($websiteid)->setPrice($price_aud)->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are AUD prices the default ones? To me it looks like you're loading the default data with this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$p['sku']);
```

It should be something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setWebsiteId($websiteid)->loadByAttribute('sku',$p['sku']);
```

I think this loop should work:

```
if ( $basecurrency == "USD" ) { 

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setWebsiteId($websiteid)->loadByAttribute('sku',$p['sku']);
$product->setPrice($price_usd)->save();
                }
                elseif  ( $basecurrency == “AUD" ) { 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setWebsiteId($websiteid)->loadByAttribute('sku',$p['sku']);
                    $product->setPrice($price_aud)->save();
                }
```